# Field 'id' expected a number but got <User: Aditya@123>

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-users

I am using nested serializer for Django user module and BookDetail where user is Foreign key in BookDetail model. For perform_create method I am getting this error. Instead of considering id, self.request.user is considering username

```
class BookDetailsList(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = BookDetailsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book_Detail.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user)
```

I tried different ways to get id but I am always getting <User: Aditya@123>. I am expecting to get User Model "id" in perform_create method

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Book_Detail(models.Model):
    def nameFile(instance, filename):
        user = User.objects.get(username=instance.user_id)
        return '/'.join([str(user.username), filename])

    book_isbn = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_page = models.IntegerField()
    book_medium = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_genre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    book_cover_page = models.ImageField(upload_to=nameFile, blank=True)
    book_last_page = models.ImageField(upload_to=nameFile, blank=True)
    book_page1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=nameFile, blank=True)
    book_page2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=nameFile, blank=True)
    book_page3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=nameFile, blank=True)
    book_rental = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    book_price = models.FloatField()
    book_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    posted_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
```

serializers.py

```
from authentication.serializers import UserSerializer

class BookDetailsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book_Detail
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
from .models import Book_Detail
from .serializers import BookDetailsSerializer
from rest_framework import permissions

class BookDetailsList(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = BookDetailsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book_Detail.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user)
```

I am getting this error

```
Internal Server Error: /api/sell/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2018, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'User'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 671, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 812, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 863, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1006, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1047, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1791, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1659, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1583, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
                 ^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1584, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1585, in <listcomp>
    self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj))
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1523, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1144, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 925, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2703, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2020, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <User: Aditya@123>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 55, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 242, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\Desktop\bookmart\bookmart\sell\views.py", line 15, in perform_create
    serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 981, in create
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `Book_Detail.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Book_Detail.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the BookDetailsSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2018, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'User'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 671, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 812, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 863, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1006, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1047, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1791, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1659, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1583, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
                 ^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1584, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1585, in <listcomp>
    self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj))
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1523, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1144, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 925, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2703, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Pandit\.virtualenvs\bookmart-ugZrwS1X\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2020, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <User: Aditya@123>.
```

Answer (score 2):

`user_id` is a special term which means the literal PK of User, but request.user is the User object

Two ways you can do this:

###### Using the object

```py
# No _id
serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

###### Using the PK

```py
# user.pk 
serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user.pk)
```

---

#### Edit

Just to clarify, this `_id` keyword works for all ForeignKeys: `{field}_id`

Comment: I tried both ways I am getting this error django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

Comment: That's a different error, it's usually caused by a `.get()` command that's not returning any user. The only time I can see `request.user` tripping that error is if you aren't logged in.. So I think this error is elsewhere, the error msg should tell you the exact line

Comment: I am checking output on postman where I have supplied beaer token in authorization and user_id equals to current logged in user's id from User model. still I am getting Field 'id' expected a number but got <User: Aditya@123> error

Answer (score 0):

For both filtering and creating, you use the primary key of the user:

```
class BookDetailsList(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = BookDetailsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user.pk)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book_Detail.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.pk)
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Book_Detail`</s> to `BookDetail`.